# Pandas how to search one df for a certain date and return that data

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have two data frames and I am trying to search each row by date in the user.csv file and find the  corresponding date in the Raven.csv file and then return the Price from the df1 and the date and amount from df2.

This is working but my Price is returning a value like this [[0.11465]], is there a way to remove these brackets or a better way to do this?

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_csv('Raven.csv',)
df2 = pd.read_csv('User.csv')
df1 = df1.reset_index(drop=False)
df1.columns = ['index', 'Date', 'Price']

df2['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['Timestamp'], format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").dt.date
df1['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Date'], format="%Y-%m-%d").dt.date

Looper = 0
Date = []
Price = []
amount = []
total_value = []

for x in df2['Timestamp']:
  search = df2['Timestamp'].values[Looper]
  Date.append(search)
  price =(df1.loc[df1['Date'] == search,['index']] )
  value = df1['Price'].values[price]
  Price.append(value)
  payout = df2['Amount'].values[Looper]
  amount.append(payout)
  payout_value = value * payout
  total_value.append(payout_value)
  Looper = Looper + 1

dict = {'Date': Date, 'Price': Price, 'Payout': amount, "Total Value": total_value}  
df = pd.DataFrame(dict) 
df.to_csv('out.csv')
```

Comment: If I understood this correctly, is it not a join on the `date` field followed  by subsetting of the required columns? The `total value` value field can be computed at the end.  This way is faster, more concise and you should not face the problem of nesting.

Answer (score 0):

You can do indexing to get the value:

```
value = [[0.11465]][0][0]
print(value)
```

You get:

```
0.11465
```

I hope this is what you need.